# Any word or phrase for changing defeat to victory in a short time?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

Is there a word or a phrase that describes a situation where you were losing nearly completely but you strongly fight back to win nearly completely? Words like "victory" or "triumph" cannot express this situation very well. The change of situation should be expressed.